# Create an object onblur - but only create that object once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a new object when an onblur event takes place:

```
function example(item) {

    this.item = $(item);

    this.item.blur(function() {
        var self = this;
        new testObject(self.item);
   }
}
```

But I only want to create the testObject once. I don't want a new object each time the blur event occurs. I want to somehow create it once and then on subsequent blurs just run that stored object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean with 'run that stored object'? You're creating an object. What you mean is to just create it if it doesn't exist? If it's that, then:

```
var testObjectInstance = null;
function example(item) {
    this.item = $(item);

    this.item.blur(function() {
        var self = this;
        if (!testObjectInstance) testObjectInstance = new testObject(self.item);
   }
}
```

You could also make sure you only execute the event handler once:

```
var testObjectInstance;
function example(item) {
    this.item = $(item);

    this.item.one('blur', function() {
        var self = this;
        testObjectInstance = new testObject(self.item);
   }
}
```

the *one()* method of a jQuery object binds a handler to an event, but unbinds it automatically after it executes once.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable captured in the closure you're using as event handler:

```
function example(item) {

    this.item = $(item);
    var testobj = null;
    var self = this;

    this.item.blur(function() {
        if (testobj === null) {
            testobj = new testObject(self.item);
        }
        // ... here use testobj ...
    });
}
```

Note that `self = this` should probably be placed outside the closure because as it's used now in your example code it doesn't make much sense.